# "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" without no more information in the stdout or the debug file

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, continuous-integration

I had a build on our CI server failing with this message:

```
+ npm run coverage

> trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 coverage /home/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ololCloud_service-monitor_PR-3568
> nyc --reporter=lcov --include='**/*.js' npm run test:ci

> trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 test:ci /home/jenkins/workspace/workspace/erayCloud_service-monitor_PR-3568
> TLL_MONITOR_UPLOAD_WAIT_TIME=0 TLL_DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT=0 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --timeout 120000 --reporter=xunit --reporter-options output=./test-results/TEST-results.xml --require @babel/register  --exit ./test/monitor-unit-test-suite.js

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 test:ci: `TLL_MONITOR_UPLOAD_WAIT_TIME=0 TLL_DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT=0 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --timeout 120000 --reporter=xunit --reporter-options output=./test-results/TEST-results.xml --require @babel/register  --exit ./test/monitor-unit-test-suite.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 test:ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2021-10-21T19_09_07_920Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 coverage: `nyc --reporter=lcov --include='**/*.js' npm run test:ci`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2021-10-21T19_09_08_438Z-debug.log
script returned exit code 1
```

There is no information in these logs, and the mentioned file `2021-10-21T19_09_08_438Z-debug.log` does not have anything else either.

How can I find the information I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Look for files where the error messages might have been saved to. There may be hints in console output.

---

It is up to the apps called by NPM to print the needed information. In other words: you probably should change your build code (probably your `package.json`) to display the log you need. Often, it is not practical or even viable, but that's the general approach.

OTOH, sometimes the information is being sent to a different place. For example, consider the line below, taken from the output in the question and broken into lines for more legibility:

```
npm ERR! trololol-cloud-monitor-service@4.3.10 test:ci: 
  `TLL_MONITOR_UPLOAD_WAIT_TIME=0\TLL_DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT=0 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha 
    --timeout 120000
    --reporter=xunit
    --reporter-options output=./test-results/TEST-results.xml
    --require @babel/register
    --exit ./test/monitor-unit-test-suite.js`
```

Notice that `./node_modules/.bin/mocha` has the flag `--reporter-options output=./test-results/TEST-results.xml`. It is not hard to imagine test results are written to the file `./test-results/TEST-results.xml`. Our error messages are more likely there.

Indeed, I looked there and found these lines:

```
<testcase
  classname="Utils tests Config Watcher Tests Reload Config"
  name="Should reload configs, after file events" time="1.002">
    <failure>the string &#x22;Reload wait timeout 1000ms exceeded&#x22; was thrown, throw an Error :)
Error: the string &#x22;Reload wait timeout 1000ms exceeded&#x22; was thrown, throw an Error :)</failure>
</testcase>
<testcase
  classname="Utils tests Config Watcher Tests Schedule Reload"
  name="Should reload config, after scheduled reload" time="1.001">
    <failure>the string &#x22;Reload wait timeout 1000ms exceeded&#x22; was thrown, throw an Error :)
Error: the string &#x22;Reload wait timeout 1000ms exceeded&#x22; was thrown, throw an Error :)</failure>
</testcase>
```

There it is, the root cause of the build failure.

The rule of thumb is :

> #### Look for files where the command's output might have been saved.

Flags with words like `output`, `logfile`, `redirect` etc., are potential output redirectors.

It is not a definitive solution. You may not have access to these files on CI etc. Yet, I'd try this rule of thumb before despairing.